# Simple keyboard-less interface for playing video?

Tags: video, media

Can anyone suggest a simple GUI that works with a remote control from which I can play video files and DVDs, and mount removable media? Preferably not MythTV, because I already spent two weeks trying to set that up, and it's still not working. Something that I can put in my `~/.xsessionrc` that just works, or works after editing a simple configuration file and the like.

Comment: What did you end up using?  I've used mplayer and http://sourceforge.net/projects/mywebplayer/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) for this.